# Как получить массив данных в шаблоне blade из котроллера?

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, мне нужно получить массив в шаблоне, но когда я это пытаюсь сделать возникает надпись "Undefined variable: listMessages" подскажите что делаю не так?

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function save(Request $request) {

        $message = $request->input('message');

        if(!$message) {
            $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Введите сообщение</p>";
        } else {
            $mes = new Message();
            $mes->from = $request->input('from');
            $mes->to = $request->input('to');
            $mes->email = $request->input('email');
            $mes->message = $request->input('message');
            $mes->save();

            $answer = "<p style='color: green;'>Сообщение отправлено</p>";

        }

        return $answer;
    }

    public function getAll() {

        $listMessages = Message::all()->where('email', '=', Auth::email()->email);

        return $listMessages;
    }
}
```

```css
Route::post('/home', 'MessageController@getAll');
```

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">All users</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Мои сообщения</button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Заголовок 1</li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Заголовок 1</li>
                                    <li>CSS</li>
                                </ul>

                        </div>
                    </ul>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-left" role="navigation">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                @if (session('status'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        {{ session('status') }}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                                <?php
/*                              use App\User;
                                use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
                                $users = User::all()->except(Auth::id());?>

                                    //тот массив который пробую достать
                                    @foreach($listMessages as $message)
                                        {{$message}}
                                    @endforeach
                                    
                                @foreach($users as $user)
                                    <form method="POST" action="message">
                                        @csrf
                                        {{$user->name}}<br>
                                        <em>{{$user->email}}</em><br>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Написать сообщение</button><br>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="from" value={{Auth::user()->name}}>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="to" value={{$user->name}}>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="email" value={{$user->email}}>
                                    </form><br>
                                @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>

               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Laravel ошибка Undefined variable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004623/laravel-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-undefined-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Что бы передать переменные из контроллера в шаблонизатор используйте это:

Замените

```
return $listMessages;
```

на

```
return view('index', [
  'listMessages' => $listMessages
]);
```

index - это название шаблона index.blade.php

Comment: Спасибо за помощь я пробовал так уже но не выходит вот мои роуты

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('message', function () {
    return view('message');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('/contact', 'MessageController@save')->name('contact');

Route::post('/home', 'MessageController@getAll');

Comment: Он не доходит до шаблона этот массив

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно освоить работу с контроллерами (https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/controllers). 
Строчка (return $listMessages;) выведет белую страницу с данными переменной сверху вниз. 
Стандартный способ вывести страницу blade с передачей в неё данных выглядит так:

```
    public function getAll()
        {
            $listMessages1 = 'example1';
            $listMessages2 = 'example2';
            return view('index', compact('listMessages1', 'listMessages2'));
        }
```

Где 
**index** - это имя страницы blade (полное имя index.blade.php);
**listMessages1** - это первая переменная переданная в view  (соответствует $prod1);
**listMessages2** - это вторая переменная, и по примеру переменных может быть сколько угодно!
Надеюсь смог помочь!)