# Laravel ошибка Undefined variable

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте можете подсказать причину ошибки Undefined variable при передачи массива в шаблон blade?

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function save(Request $request) {

        $message = $request->input('message');

        if(!$message) {
            $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Введите сообщение</p>";
        } else {
            $mes = new Message();
            $mes->from = $request->input('from');
            $mes->to = $request->input('to');
            $mes->email = $request->input('email');
            $mes->message = $request->input('message');
            $mes->save();

            $answer = "<p style='color: green;'>Сообщение отправлено</p>";

        }

        return $answer;
    }

    public function getAll() {

        $listMessages = Message::all()->where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email);

        /*return view('message', [
            'listMessages' => $listMessages
        ]);*/

        return view('home',compact('listMessages'));
    }
}
```

```css
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('message', function () {
    return view('message');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('/contact', 'MessageController@save')->name('contact');

Route::post('/home', 'MessageController@getAll');
```

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">All users</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            @foreach($listMessages as $message)

                {{$message}}

            @endforeach
            
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
 Выполнить код
```

Comment: Что возвращает `compact('listMessages')`?

Comment: По идеи коллекцию объектов

Comment: По идее? Проверь что он в себе содержит

Comment: Я уже проверял он возвращает массив Json но когда в home я хочу получить возвращает Undefined variable: listMessages

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пытаетесь обратится через адресную строку в браузере по роуту `/home` , то у вас отрабатывает данный роут `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')`.
Если вы хотите что бы отработал ваш роут, то обратитесь через `post` или измените его на `get`.
Например:
    `Route::get('/all-messages', 'MessageController@getAll');`

Comment: Да спасибо просто нужен был get запрос